# Magento 2.2 REST API Call to get media, does not return base 64 string

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api, magento2.2.7

I tried the call

> /V1/products/:sku/media/

I get this response

```
[{
        "id": 31,
        "media_type": "image",
        "label": null,
        "position": 1,
        "disabled": false,
        "types": [
            "image",
            "small_image",
            "thumbnail",
            "swatch_image"
        ],
        "file": "/9/1/91sh_fuln0l._ux342__1.jpg"
    }]
```

Expected response as per dev docs contains the object

```
 "content": {
      "base64_encoded_data": "string",
      "type": "string",
      "name": "string"
    },
```

Does anyone know why it is missing?